# printing the array in reverse order-why is this wrong in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to print the array in the reverse order.
And I can't understand why this is impossible.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int str[100];
int len=0;

printf("Array: ");
scanf("%s",str);

while(str[len]!=0)
    len++;

for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
printf("%c",str[i]);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: C or C++? If you're using C++ you should be using `<iostream>` for one.

Comment: What do you mean by "impossible"? What happens when you compile, and run this code?

Comment: `char str[100];`

Comment: Many modern compilers will warn about the format argument-parameter type mis-match in `scanf("%s", str);`, but not all. If you get a warning , don't ignore it. Understand and resolve it. If you really do want the behaviour, and I can't see why you would in this case, you can live with the warning, juggle the code slightly so that the compiler will recognize you really do want the unusual behaviour, or turn off that type of warning and hope you don't miss a legitimate diagnostic.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't working for a few reasons:

- You're not reading numbers into the array correctly
- You're treating your array as as string, but it's an array of ints
- You're assuming the array is 0-delimited, which is really bad for an array of ints and results in undefined behavior
- You're trying to print out the array as though it were a string, but it's an array of ints

Let's break things down into parts that do each job. First: printing an array in reverse:

```
void print_in_reverse(int* ptr, int len) {
    for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%i ", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This will print an array of ints in reverse based on the length of the array.

The second task is reading in the array. We need to check for `EOF`, or the End of File, because if someone presses `Ctrl-D` (or `Ctrl-Z` in windows) in the terminal, that will indicate that there's no more input and `scanf` will return `EOF`.

```
int read_in_array(int* arr, int max_len) {
    int num_read = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < max_len; i++) {
        // Read into the ith element
        int flag = scanf("%i", &(arr[i]));
        if(flag == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        num_read++;
    }
    return num_read;
}
```

This will read in up to `max_len` ints. It will also return the number it read successfully.

Now, we can put them together:

```
int main() {
    int arr[100];

    int num_read = read_in_array(arr, 100);

    print_in_reverse(arr, num_read);
}
```

When I compile and run it, I get the following output:

```
11:46:09 perez ~$ g++ test.cpp 
11:46:10 perez ~$ ./a.out
10
20
30
30 20 10
```

I entered `10 20 30`, and then pressed `Ctrl+D` to indicate that I had no more numbers. The program then responded with `30 20 10`

Comment: Note that Ctrl+D is not enforced by anything but convention. It is used by most of the *nix consoles I've seen. The Windows equivalent is typically Ctrl+Z